# How to use an allocatable array of types containing allocatable arrays in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, segmentation-fault, gfortran, derived-types

I have defined a type that contains an allocatable array, and I want to use an allocatable array composed of variables of this type. However, when I pass this array to a subroutine, I can't access the elements as expected. I'm using gfortran 10.2.0 on MacOS 10.14.6.

Here's a short code that reproduces the bug:

```
module broken_stuff

  type mat_type
    integer :: n_elems
    real, allocatable :: elems(:)
  end type mat_type

contains

  subroutine test()
    type(mat_type), allocatable :: d(:, :)
    integer :: i, j

    ! Allocate d
    allocate(d(-10 : 10, -10 : 10))

    ! Assign values to d(3, 4)
    d(3, 4)%n_elems = 3
    allocate(d(3,4)%elems(3))
    d(3,4)%elems(1:3) = (/1.2, 3.4, 5.6/)

    ! Allocate unused parts of d to size 0
    do i = -10, 10
      do j = -10, 10
        if (i == 3 .and. j == 4)  cycle
        allocate(d(i, j)%elems(0))
      enddo ! j
    enddo ! i

    ! Print out components of d(3, 4)
    write (6,*) "DEBUG 1:"
    write (6,*) d(3, 4)%n_elems
    write (6,*) d(3, 4)%elems

    ! Pass d into a routine that prints out same components again
    call print_component(d)

    ! Print out same components one more time
    write (6,*) "DEBUG 3:"
    write (6,*) d(3, 4)%n_elems
    write (6,*) d(3, 4)%elems
  end subroutine test

  subroutine print_component(d)
    type(mat_type), intent(in) :: d(:, :)

    write (6,*) "DEBUG 2:"
    write (6,*) d(3, 4)%n_elems
    write (6,*) d(3, 4)%elems
  end subroutine print_component

end module broken_stuff

program broken
  use broken_stuff
  call test()
end program broken
```

Output from accessing the same element three times (should be the same, no?):

```
 DEBUG 1:
           3
   1.20000005       3.40000010       5.59999990    
 DEBUG 2:
           0

 DEBUG 3:
           3
   1.20000005       3.40000010       5.59999990
```

Do you know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: I would start with UBOUND and LBOUND and have the routine sperite out those. And changing allocate from 0 to 1 may provide some insight.

Comment: @Holmz Thanks. (lbound, ubound) are (-10, 10) outside of the subroutine and (1, 21) inside. Is the issue that the lbound doesn't stick with the array when it's passed to a subroutine?

Comment: if the subroutine shows dimensions of (1:21,1;21), can index 3,4 then jump to 14,15? So LBOUND and UBOUND can go into the call as dimensions for the array...